# esp8266 (ESP-07S) draws 100 micro amps in deep sleep instead of 20 as documented

Tags: arduino, batteries, esp8266, low-power

I have a quite simple circuit using ESP-07S module (esp8266 chip, no USB, no LEDs).
The device, after performing some operations enters deep sleep and waits for a button connected to RST to wake up (no timer, no GPIO16 connection to RST).
ESP-07S is connected to I2C OLED, and RTC DS3231. To go to deep sleep I use following Arduino code:

```
  WiFi.mode( WIFI_OFF );
  WiFi.forceSleepBegin();
  delay(1);
  WiFi.persistent( false );
  display.ssd1306_command(SSD1306_DISPLAYOFF);
  delay(10);
  Serial.end();
  pinMode(0, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(4, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(5, INPUT_PULLUP);  
  pinMode(13, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(16, INPUT_PULLUP);
  ESP.deepSleep(0, RF_DISABLED);
```

Not sure if the INPUT_PULLUP on all pins is needed.
In deep sleep the device still uses 100 micro amp (at 3V). Even after disconnecting OLED and RTC.
So something must be wrong, documentation says it should take 20 micro amps in deep sleep.

1. Should I add something in code to reduce power consumption in deep sleep?
2. Should I set some configuration in Arduino IDE (I use generic ESP8266 board, default config)
3. Some sources recommend to reduce CPU frequency from 80MHz to 20MHz - how to do it? Arduino IDE gives only options for 80 and 160.

**UPDATE**

I found the reason of additional current - it is DS3231. If I disconnet it completely, the current drops to expected 20 micro amps.
If only Vcc is disconnected from DS3231 current somehow leaks through SDA and SCK pins. So it seems that I have to somehow disable I2C in software before going to sleep. Any advice?

Comment: Following this https://docs.ai-thinker.com/_media/esp8266/docs/esp-07s_product_specification_en.pdf ... 20 uA is measured @2.5V, page 11, Deep Sleep.

Comment: Yes, but still 100micro amp at 3V seems tu much.

Comment: Is the ds3231 a ‘real’ Maxim device? There’s plenty of fakes in the market and who knows what their specs are.  Are you using the cheapy ds3231 boards that cost less than an actual ds3231 chip?

Comment: It is true, that the board I use is some unbranded cheap stuff...